# Android: viewing tabular data

Tags: java, android

In android, there is the ListActivity. However, what if I want multiple lists in the same Activity? For instance:

### Vehicles    [Add Vehicle]

1999 Ford Focus
2001 Nissan Altima

### Drivers    [Add Driver]

John Doe
Jane Doe

How would I create a view like what you see above?  The list of vehicles and list of drivers would be populated based on `List<Vehicle>` and `List<Driver>`, respectively.

I want functionality like the `<h:DataTable>` in JSF.

Also, I know about the TableLayout. However, that doesn't help me since I can't attach an array adapter to it or anything like that.

Comment: Is your question how to have two ListViews on the screen? i.e. how to set up the layout?

Comment: Answering that would work But more generally, how do I include Lists in the general flow of a layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there's the `ListView` element, which is what a `ListActivity` uses.

If you want to have several of those, you could put both of them into a `LinearLayout` and give each one a `weight` of 1 so they share the screen. They will have scrolling functionality built in, and scroll independently.